# Add new line in javascript string when sharing text

Tags: javascript, string

I'm building a string and sharing it in an email. Problem is that everything is in the same line (it works fine when the string is built in the server side)

```
    var sharing_txt = "";
    sharing_txt = sharing_txt.concat("hello");
    sharing_txt = sharing_txt.concat("\n");
    sharing_txt = sharing_txt.concat("hello");
    window.location.href = "mailto:?subject="+'hello subject'+"&body="+sharing_txt;
```

console output:
hello
hello

Email:
hellohello

Comment: what is actually the problem?

Comment: Why did u down vote? read the question...

Comment: i did not dv, but i do not understand what you have, what you got and what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `%0D` as the new line (Carriage return).

```js
var sharing_txt = "";
sharing_txt = sharing_txt.concat("Hello");
sharing_txt = sharing_txt.concat("%0D");
sharing_txt = sharing_txt.concat("Ele");

document.getElementById('mailto').setAttribute('href', "mailto:?subject=" + 'hello subject' + "&body=" + sharing_txt);
```

```html
<a id='mailto'>Send</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of \n use HTML breakline br

```
<br/>
```

New line not recognised in browser.
Try.